# Client Generation in web service(jax)

Tags: web-services, jax-ws

I made a web service endpoint and exposed a method now i wanna add more parameter to my method
so each time i change in my method i have to regenerate my client. Is there any way so that i
dont have to generate my client again and again.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way. If you change the method then the `WSDL` file is changed also. Web services communicates through `SOAP` between client and server. When you deploy your web service application and it has been changed, so how then client supposed to know if there is a new method or a new parameters added if the classes was generated from the old `WSDL` file. Client will send a `SOAP` request according to the old `WSDL` and the server won't be able to understand the `SOAP` message received from the client if there was any changes made to `WSDL` part related to the received message.

Answer (score 0):

You could design a better webservice/endpoint that accepts a standalone xml document as argument so that the operation signature stays the same, even when you add more parameters.

More generally, it's bad form for a web service to expose it operations as literal method signatures.